# Ansible imbricated with_item

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to imbricate 2 with_item.

At the moment I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
- name: Create log folder
  file:
    dest={{ item.dest }} # item from first with_item
    state=directory
    mode=0755
  with_items:
    { dest: "{{ item.path_logs }}/gunicorn" } # item from flask apps
    { dest: "{{ item.path_logs }}/nginx" } # item from flask apps
    { dest: "{{ item.path_logs }}/supervisor" } # item from flask apps
  with_items: "{{ flask_apps }}"
```

Is it possible to do it or should I make 3 tasks ?

Comment: Still not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of [nested loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops) in the documentation.
For your case:

```
- name: Create log folder
  file:
    dest: "{{ item.0.path }}/{{ item.1 }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  with_nested:
    - "{{ flask_apps }}"
    - ['gunicorn','nginx','supervisor']
```